# Camera's string parameters under Android API 7 (2.1 Eclair)

Tags: android, android-camera

I am developping an application that uses the `Camera` preview, take picture, and zoom functions.

I am trying to remain compatible with the Android API level 7 (2.1 Eclair), which does not implement `Camera.Parameters.getMaxZoom()`, `Camera.Parameters.setZoom()`, etc, so I have to use the `String` parameters returned by the hardware. For example:

```
final String zoomSupportedString = parameters.get("zoom-supported"); // parameters is a Camera.Parameters 
final boolean zoomSupported = (zoomSupportedString != null ? Boolean.parseBoolean(zoomSupportedString) : false);

if (zoomSupported) {
    // Computes the min an max zoom levels for taking a picture:
    final int minTake = parameters.getInt("taking-picture-zoom-min");
    final int maxTake = parameters.getInt("taking-picture-zoom-max"); 

    // etc.
}
```

But not all the devices use the same parameters, and I couldn't find any valid camera parameters list on the internet.

By checking the values returned by `Camera.Parameters.flatten()` (see [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#flatten%28%29)) on a HTC I could find `"zoom-supported"`, `"taking-picture-zoom-min"`, `"taking-picture-zoom-max"` and `"max-zoom"`. And surprisingly, I have found no `"min-zoom"`.

But the parameter `"taking-picture-zoom-min"` doesn't exist on Samsung Galaxy S, for example, and this leads `null` to be returned and `getInt()` to throw a `NumberFormatException: 'null' cannot be parsed as an integer`.

Knowing that I am trying to remain compatible with Android-7, is there any better way to handle the zoom than using the string values returned by the hardware? And if so, is it possible to find somewhere a list of all the valid zoom parameters (or even a list by vendor)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i know it's an old topic, but for those that are searching for Camera zoom... i had the same issue and now that i have 2 android devices which work differently, both had something in commmon.

`Camera.Parameters.setZoom(int value)` didn't work on both of them, so i started testing. One device has "taking-picture-zoom-...;" but both devices have "zoom=...;" in the Camera.Parameters. On the device that has "taking-picture-zoom-...;", if i use `Camera.Parameters.set("zoom", int value)` it would crash, while on the other it would work just fine. So, my solution is, when initializing the camera I store a boolean that holds true for `Camera.Parameters.get("taking-picture-zoom")!=null`, and false otherwise. From that moment on, when setting zoom, just check the boolean and use the appropriate zoom-command... and that's it, works like a charm ! ofcourse, you could also just make a String hold the appropriate command and use that when setting zoom.